# retrieving heterogenous elements from xml in haskell

Tags: xml, haskell

I have a big .xml file which I load and parse in Haskell using `Text.XML.Light`. The elements in the file represent different objects. It somewhat looks like this:

```
<matchhistory>
  <game starttime="2/10/13 18:00" endtime="2/11/13 18:40">
    <participant>
      <name>John Doe</name>
      <color>green</color>
    </participant>
    <participant>
      <name>Jane Doe</name>
      <color>blue</color>
    </participant>
    <winner color="blue">
  </game>
  <game starttime="2/11/13 17:00" endtime="2/11/13 17:30">
    <participant>
      <name>Jane Doe</name>
      <color>green</color>
    </participant>
    <participant>
      <name>John Doe</name>
      <color>blue</color>
    </participant>
    <winner color="green">
  </game>
  ...
</matchhistory>
```

I want to iterate through the nodes and retrieve the objects. What would be a good way to store the data in Haskell for further processing? As an example, I'm interested in the average time they played the games.

Would it make sense to create data types in a similar nested way?

```
data Participant = Participant {name :: String,
                                color :: String}

data Game = Game {starttime :: UTCTime, 
                  endtime :: UTCTime,
                  participants :: [Participant],
                  winner :: String}

data MatchHistory = MatchHistory {games :: [Game]}
```

How would I perform this conversion, going through the whole file (26K lines) seperately to extract each object type does not seem very elegant? Is there a nice way (maybe with pattern matching for calling different constructors) to do so in one sweep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this would be a good way to structure this code.  Using your data definitions, I was able to pretty easily figure out how to turn your example XML document into a data structure.  The trick here is to build incremental parsers.

First, we need some imports and a restatement of the data definitions:

```hs
import Data.Time (UTCTime)
import Data.Time.Format (parseTime)
import System.Locale (defaultTimeLocale)
import Data.Maybe (mapMaybe)
import Text.XML.Light
import Control.Applicative ((<$>), (<*>))

data Participant = Participant
    { name  :: String
    , color :: String
    } deriving (Eq, Show)

data Game = Game
    { starttime     :: UTCTime
    , endtime       :: UTCTime
    , participants  :: [Participant]
    , winner        :: String
    } deriving (Eq, Show)

data MatchHistory = MatchHistory
    { games :: [Game]
    } deriving (Eq, Show)
```

We can use the `parseXML` function in `Text.XML.Light` to convert a string to `[Content]`.  Next, we can extract all the top-level elements using `onlyElems`.  For parsing, we want each parse to be able to fail gracefully, so for now we'll just use the `Maybe` monad.  We can make a stub for each data type:

```
parseParticipant :: Element -> Maybe Participant
parseParticipant = undefined

parseGame :: Element -> Maybe Game
parseGame = undefined

parseMatchHistory :: Element -> Maybe MatchHistory
parseMatchHistory = undefined
```

This lets us write a document parser:

```
parseDocument :: String -> [MatchHistory]
parseDocument = mapMaybe parseMatchHistory . onlyElems . parseXML
```

Now, for the implementations of each parse:

```
parseParticipant pElem = Participant
    <$> (strContent <$> findChild (blank_name { qName = "name"  }) pElem)
    <*> (strContent <$> findChild (blank_name { qName = "color" }) pElem)
```

This one is easy, we have two text fields, all we have to do is find each field then extract the text.  I've chosen the applicative style here because I think it's easier, but we'll use the monadic style as well.

```
parseGame gElem = do
    starttimeStr <- findAttrBy (("starttime" ==) . qName) gElem
    endtimeStr <- findAttrBy (("endtime" ==) . qName) gElem
    winnerElem <- findChild (blank_name { qName = "winner" }) gElem
    let pElems = filterChildrenName (("participant" ==) . qName) gElem
    ...
```

So now we've extracted pretty much all the information from the game element we need, we just have to parse the time strings into `UTCTime`, parse each participant, and then return a `Game` value.  For the time parsing, I'll introduce an extra function to make it easy:

```
parseTimeField :: String -> Maybe UTCTime
parseTimeField = parseTime defaultTimeLocale "%-m/%-d/%-y %R"

parseGame gElem = do
    starttimeStr <- findAttrBy (("starttime" ==) . qName) gElem
    endtimeStr <- findAttrBy (("endtime" ==) . qName) gElem
    winnerElem <- findChild (blank_name { qName = "winner" }) gElem
    let pElems = filterChildrenName (("participant" ==) . qName) gElem
    Game <$> parseTimeField starttimeStr
         <*> parseTimeField endtimeStr
         <*> pure (mapMaybe parseParticipant pElems)
         <*> findAttrBy (("color" ==) . qName) winnerElem
```

Finally, we need to implement `parseMatchHistory`.  I'll leave this one as an exercise for you, but it should be very easy.

Once you have a parsed document, you can do things like

```
averageTimePlayed :: MatchHistory -> DiffTime
averageTimePlayed = average . map calcDiff . games
    where
        average xs = sum xs / fromIntegral (length xs)
        calcDiff g = endtime g `diffUTCTime` starttime g
```

Although through the magic of lenses, you could probably make this shorter.

Comment: I like the way `mapMaybe` and `parseXYZ` play together. It leads to a really clear and concise implementation. The same can be said about your answer to my question. :)

Comment: @j.dog Glad to hear it.  You could certainly reduce a bit of the repetition in this a bit cleaner, too, I'm imagining something more like [this](https://gist.github.com/bheklilr/3f6dd0928effd4fd37bf)